# Failed to start mongo.service on ubuntu 16.04 after update from 4.0 to 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.2

I'm trying to update my MongoDB installation from 3.6 to the latest version [4.4] on Ubuntu16.04 using apt-get. Going from 4.0 to 4.2 I faced a problem during the startup process after updating the binaries and mongo.log shows the exception below:

> 2020-08-07T14:58:26.205+0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location40415: BSON field 'MinValidDocument.oplogDeleteFromPoint' is an unknown field., terminating

I'm using WiredTiger and I checked the feature compatibility version and other prerequisites according to the installation and the compatibility docs and everything looks fine. I also tried mongod repair but with no luck.

I don't have any clue on what could be the source of this problem and I'd be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appeared after updating the binaries to version 4.2. When I start the mongo service, the service fails to start and the log shows this exception before it starts the shutdown procedure:

```
2020-08-07T14:58:26.205+0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location40415: BSON field 'MinValidDocument.oplogDeleteFromPoint' is an unknown field., terminating
```

According to @JJussi, the 'oldOplogDeleteFromPoint' isn't supposed to be there since it was removed from versions > 3.4 which turned out to be the problem in my case. The solution was to unset the 'oplogDeleteFromPoint' like @Pavel_Duchovny advised [here](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/failed-to-start-mongo-service-after-update-from-4-0-to-4-2/7640/4?u=anas_obeidat). After that, I updated the binaries and the service started normally.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.. It should not be possible...  From the source:

```
    cpp_name: oldOplogDeleteFromPoint
￼                type: timestamp
￼                optional: true # This field only exists on 3.4 upgrade
￼                description: "The timestamp of the first oplog entry in a batch when we are writing
￼                              oplog entries to the oplog after which the oplog may be inconsistent.
￼                              This field only exists on 3.4 upgrade."
```

And this problem only exists on unclean upgrade from <=3.4 version. It is removed from source code at version 3.8 forward.

Yes, I know, this answer doesn't solve the problem, but... It looks like that your upgrade process was not "by the book", sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JJussi!

Yes, you're 100% right, this installation was actually upgraded before from version 3.2. I don't know what could have been done wrong in the last update but it's clear that there was a problem because I haven't found any other questions for a similar issue.

However, the solution was to simply unset the value of 'oplogDeleteFromPoint' and upgrade the Mongodb binaries. I don't know if there are other problems that may arise in the future but this did the trick for now.